# How to build a JSON data array for Highcharts display - switching values for xAxis/columns

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, highcharts

I have a column chart which is being displayed with JSON data being parsed over in "normal" form: Years on the xAxis, values on yAxis ([fiddle here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/luftikus143/tyzwzzy7/)):

```
    array(
        array(
            "name" => "Bangladesh", 
            "data" => 
                array(
                    array(2000,27892), 
                    array(2010,56199)
                )
        ), 
        array(
            "name" => "Sri Lanka", 
            "data" => 
                array(
                    array(2000, 10170), 
                    array(2010,12720)
                )
        )
    )
```

Now, I'd like to switch the display: the countries (instead of years) should be on the xAxis, and the columns should represent the years. I was fiddling around with the data array, switching the country names with the years like this:

```
    array(
        array(
            "name" => 2000, 
            "data" => 
                array(
                    array("Bangladesh",27892), 
                    array("Sri Lanka",10170)
                )
        ), 
        array(
            "name" => 2010, 
            "data" => 
                array(
                    array("Bangladesh",56199), 
                    array("Sri Lanka",12720)
                )
        )
    );
```

and indeed, the columns are now the right display. However, the xAxis shows "0" and "1" instead of "Bangladesh" and "Sri Lanka".

Can anyone give me a hint what would be the right fix? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in your fiddle - categories array set for x axis is the reason why labels are as they are. So you should also update categories array in x axis - 
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.update

Comment: The fiddle is different from the JSON array, as indeed there, the xAxis is being set. The JSON array is being "imported" into Highcharts as it is. So, it's there, within that array, that I'd need to change the data structure in order to get the result I want.

Comment: Can you paste your json here, instead of php code? Have you trie to set type of xAxis as "category" ?

Comment: @Sebastian: This is what I pass to "series" in the "normal" column chart (years on xAxis): `[{"name":"Bangladesh","data":[[2007,48506],[2010,56199]]},{"name":"Sri Lanka","data":[[2007,12467],[2010,12720]]}]`. I put up [another fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/luftikus143/3bcb8sxw/1/). Interestingly, for those two items I don't succeed to have the two selected years displayed on the xAxis, but there are more years being displayed. Still fiddling around how to change the JSON code so that the countries are being displayed on the xAxis.

Answer (score 0):

Got it going now...

The xaxis should have "type: category", and the series data should be formatted as following (see [fiddle here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/luftikus143/jqtx0oou/1/)):

```
    "series": 
    [
        {"name": 2007, "data": [["Bangladesh", 48506], ["Sri Lanka", 12467]]}, 
        {"name": 2010, "data": [["Bangladesh", 56199], ["Sri Lanka", 12720]]}
    ]
```